# Detect an app installed

Tags: android, package, detect

Could I know If there is a specific app installed in the phone programmatically? My app would make a process in one way or in other depending on that. How could I get this information?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }
    return installed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **must know the package name** to check weather the application is installed or not

say if package name is like **com.myapp.name**

use the following to existence

```
boolean isExists;
try
        {
            getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myapp.name", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            isExists = true;
        }
        catch(NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            isExists = false;
            // Sep 11, 2013 8:39:47 PM
            Log.e("Exception", "NameNotFoundException" + String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Must use try catch around to handling expected error when **NameNotFoundException** is thrown